# Date not being set in session

Tags: php, html, session, date, time

I am working on a system in PHP, that allows a client to reserve their booking via a database.

Everything works fine except for one part. That part is that the `time()` and `date()` is not correctly being set in the session. Note this is not my original work, it's from a previous creator, but he is not working for the company anymore.

This is a part of the reservation script:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['mt_reservering']['startdate']) || !$_SESSION['mt_reservering']['startdate']  )
    {
        $_SESSION['mt_reservering']['startdate'] = time();
    }

    //handle post
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {

        if ($key == "startdate")
        {
            $arr_values = explode("-",$value);
            $value = time(0,0,0,$arr_values[1],$arr_values[0],$arr_values[2]);
        }

        $_SESSION['mt_reservering'][$key] = $value;
```

The input:

```
$formulier .= "
                <tr>
                    <td>Vertrekdatum:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type=\"text\" name=\"startdate\" style=\"width:175px;\" value=\"".date("d-m-Y",$_SESSION['mt_reservering']['startdate'])."\">
                        <script language=\"JavaScript\">
                        new tcal ({                                         
                            'formname': 'reservation',
                            'controlname': 'startdate'
                        });                                 
                        </script>       

                    </td>
                </tr>";
```

So the majority of this problem is that it keeps on resetting at the final step to the date of today instead of the date they have booked.

Anyone has an idea why this happens?

Some pictures to see it:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/44lWj.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/3voGN.png

Comment: Have you added the `session_start();` before the session being set?

Comment: You see, you know how to **take** the reservation, you just don't know how to **hold** the reservation. And that's really the most important part of the reservation: the holding. Anybody can just take them.

Comment: @KrishR It is, it's on the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous coder was trying to use the function mktime().
The time() function takes no arguments and returns the current timestamp always.
mktime() will format a timestamp from given values.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use time function to Set value as it only returns current unix time stamp.
use DateTime instead.